# JPA query IN clause on column with CSV values not returning exact results

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a JPA query where I need to get the correct results.

Table structure (let's call this **T1**):

[image]

and this is my JPA query:

```
@Query("from T1 t where t.csv in :ids")
List<T1> listT1Records(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

The csv column can also contain non-numeric string. when I query using raw sql it returns records **1**,**2** and **3** which is my desired result but when I debugged my code the returned result is only record **2**. I looked up everywhere for answers but found none.

Raw Sql

```
select * from T1 where csv in (11);
```

Comment: what does the ids list contain during your tests? also can you post your "raw sql" query?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi the ids contained "11".

Comment: what data type stores csv column? is seems a string (varchar) from java and table picture, but numeric from raw sql. anyway, if it stores a string, the output of jpa method is correct, record with id 2 is the only one which has the string "11" in csv column.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` cause not working like that.

1. You should to convert the list to a string operated by commat:

```
String.join(",", ids);
```

2. use the following query:

```
@Query("from T1 t where t.csv like %:ids%")
List<T1> listT1Records(@Param("ids") String ids);
```